# how to modify parent class variable with the child class and use in another child class in java

Tags: java

I have a class Test which has a variable count as 0.
Test class was extended by Classes A and B.
I set the count in A as 50.
Now i want to access the count in B, which should return the value as 50, But i'm getting as 0 in B.
I'm new to java and i dont know how it works :(
can any one help me how to implement this? :(

```
Public Class Extend { 
    public int count =0; 
} 


Public class a extends Extend { 
    this.count = 50; 
 }  

public class b extends Extend { 
   system.out.println ( " count is " + count); 
}
```

Comment: why do you think b.count should return 50? b extends Extend not a.

Answer (score 3):

Each instance of `Extend` (including instances of any class that extends it) gets its own copy of `count`. The values are not shared between instances.

You can change `b` to extend class `a` instead of class `Extend`. Then any instance of `b` would see whatever initialization was done when the `a` constructor executed.

If you want the same `count` to be shared by all instances of a class or its subclasses, then you need to make the field `static`:

```
public class Extend {
    public static int count = 0;
}
```

In subclasses, you then would refer to the field name without `this.` as a qualifier.

Note that the code you posted is not legal Java. The first two classes should be `public class`, not `Public Class` or `Public class`. Also, you cannot have code like `this.count = 50;` outside a method or initializer block. I'm assuming that this is not your real code.

Comment: Yes ted.. Its not the real code. Just the reference. Pls ingore if you find syntac issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can make it `static`. `static` fields are shared between instances; and if you change one static variable in child class, **the father**, and thus, **the instances of all child class created afterwards** will share the changed value.

Consider these classes:

Father.java

```
class Father {                              
    protected static int i;                 
    public Father() {                       
        System.out.println("Father: " + i); 
    }                                       
}
```

Child.java:

```
class Child extends Father {
    public Child() {
        i = 4;
        System.out.println("Child: i: " + i);
        System.out.println("Child: this.i: " + this.i);
        System.out.println("Child: super i: " + super.i);

    }
}
```

Daughter.java:

```
public class Daughter extends Father {
    public Daughter() {
        System.out.println("Daughter: i: " + Daughter.i);
    }
}
```

Main.java:

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("First daughter");
        Daughter daughter = new Daughter();
        Father father = new Father();
        Child child = new Child();
        System.out.println("Second daughter");
        Daughter daughter2 = new Daughter();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
First daughter         
Father: 0              
Daughter: i: 0         
Father: 0              
Father: 0              
Child: i: 4            
Child: this.i: 4       
Child: super i: 4      
Second daughter        
Father: 4              
Daughter: i: 4
```

Answer (score 0):

in class `b` you are getting the `count` from `Extend`, that's why it is `0`. You could do:

```
class b extends a {

    System.out.println("count: " + count);

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Class Extend { 
    public int count = 0; 
} 

Public class A extends Extend { 
    this.count = 50; 
}  

public class B extends Extend {
   public void showMessage() {
       //this will print 0 if you don't change count value in your main method
       system.out.println ("count is " + this.count); 
   } 
}
```

try to use this :

```
Public Class Extend { 
    public int count = 0; 
}

Public class A extends Extend { 
    this.count = 50; 
}  

public class B extends Extend { 
   private Extend myExtend;

   public B(Extend myExtend) {
       this.myExtend = myExtend;
   }

   public void showMessage() {
       system.out.println (" count is " + this.myExtend.count);
   }  
}
```

now in your main class you can use this

```
Extend eA = new A();

Extend eB = new B(eA);

eb.showMessage(); //this will print 50
```